# Laravel 4 View: Display content for specific period

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

What's the best way to display content in my view for a specific time, e.g from 1 am to 3 am?

What I have so far

```
  @if($post->publishDate < Carbon::now())
    <h4 class="text-center">{{ $post->article}}</h4>
  @endif
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[See official doc](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison), you can use the `between` method :

```
$first = Carbon::create(2012, 9, 5, 1);
$second = Carbon::create(2012, 9, 5, 5);
var_dump(Carbon::create(2012, 9, 5, 3)->between($first, $second)); // true
var_dump(Carbon::create(2012, 9, 5, 5)->between($first, $second)); // true
var_dump(Carbon::create(2012, 9, 5, 5)->between($first, $second, false)); // false
```